# How to force JQGrid to show a fixed number of rows, and fill it with empty ones if necessary

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid

I'm required to load data and always show 5 rows per page, even if I need to fill them with empty rows.
After doing some research on StackOverflow, I was able to find a little snippet that adds empty rows but it works only when the total rows are smaller than the pagesize (in my case, totalrows < 5). If my data contains more than 5 rows (for instance, 11 rows) my third page will show 5 rows (1 with data and 4 empty rows just like I want) but my first two pages will show 9 rows (5 with data and 4 empty rows).

How do I fix this? I have the following code so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $.subscribe('gridEstudiosComplete', function() {
                    var selRowIds = new Array();
                    selRowIds = $('#gridEstudios').jqGrid("getDataIDs");
                    var records = jQuery("#gridEstudios").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
                    var pagesize = jQuery("#gridEstudios").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum');
                    // if records < pagesize I add empty rows until I have 5 (this works ok) else I have to calculate how many empty rows I have to add to the last page (it doesn't work ok, I added pictures below)
                    if (records < pagesize) {
                        for (i = records - pagesize; i < pagesize; i++) {
                            $("#gridEstudios").addRowData(records + i, {});
                        }
                    } else if (records > pagesize && records % pagesize != 0) {
                        rowsToAdd = pagesize - (records % pagesize);
                        while (rowsToAdd > 0) {
                            $("#gridEstudios").addRowData(records + 1, {});
                            records = records + 1;
                            rowsToAdd = rowsToAdd - 1;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

This doesnt work ok when I have more than 5 records to show:
[image: This doesnt work ok when I have more than 5 records to show]

---

Unlike previous pages, the last one works as required:
[image: Unlike previous pages, the last one works as required]

Comment: Shouldn't you be taking into consideration what page you are on ? if you only consider the total records and the page size, you are always going to add the row. however if total records > pagesize, in theory you only want to add the rows to the final page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below i have retrieved "curpage" (Current Page) and "totalpages" (Total # of Pages) from the grid's postData object, then added as a condition in the elseif so that you would only add rows to the last page

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $.subscribe('gridEstudiosComplete', function() {
            var selRowIds=new Array();
            selRowIds=$('#gridEstudios').jqGrid("getDataIDs");
            var records = jQuery("#gridEstudios").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
            var pagesize = jQuery("#gridEstudios").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum');
            var postdata = jQuery("#gridEstudios").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
            var curpage = postdata.page
            var totalpages = postdata.total
            // if records < pagesize I add empty rows until I have 5 (this works ok) else I have to calculate how many empty rows I have to add to the last page (it doesn't work ok, I added pictures below)
            if (records < pagesize) {
                for (i = records - pagesize; i < pagesize; i++) {
                    $("#gridEstudios").addRowData(records + i, {});
                }
            } else if (records > pagesize && records % pagesize != 0 && curpage == totalpages) {
                rowsToAdd = pagesize - (records % pagesize);
                while(rowsToAdd > 0) {
                    $("#gridEstudios").addRowData(records + 1, {});
                    records = records + 1;
                    rowsToAdd = rowsToAdd - 1;
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this at work tomorrow. I did some nasty code from the server side to always send modulus of 5 records (i send empty records as a work around). Would you please explain what $.subscribe does? I have no experience whatsoever in JavaScript, I really need to learn it... Also, thank you for showing me how to retrieve current page records, wasn't aware of postData. I didn't find that property in JQGrid documentation, how did you find it?

Comment: the jqGrid documentation is .... meh.   Mostly i think of a question and search for it on stackoverflow and learn a lot more from the examples provided here :)
I dont know what $.subscribe does, i just copied it from your code example